# Gap between ket and bra by using the braket-package

Tags: packages, braket

I'm using the braket-package for using the braket notation. It works fine, but I've got some problems by using the package for writing a tensor product.

There is always a big gap between the ket and the bra by writing `\ket{x}\bra{x}`. So I want to have it like `|x><x|` and not like `|x> <x|`. Does anyone know this problem and perhaps also a solution for it?

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\ket{x}\bra{x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question would be easier to answer if you made a small complete document showing your input and the bad space then people can test answers. (you can use the `{}` button in the editor to mark a mult-line code block)

Answer (score 3):

It's “by design”. The definitions of `\bra` and `\ket` are

```
% braket.sty, line 31:
\def\bra#1{\mathinner{\langle{#1}|}}

% braket.sty, line 32:
\def\ket#1{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle}}
```

and `\mathinner` adds a thin space on either side of the construction.

If you want to remove those additional thin spaces (which is not a bad idea, by the way), you can redefine them like

```
\renewcommand\bra[1]{{\langle{#1}|}}
\renewcommand\ket[1]{{|{#1}\rangle}}
```

However, the sidebearings of `\langle` and `\rangle` will still leave a hole.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\renewcommand\bra[1]{{\langle{#1}|}}
\renewcommand\ket[1]{{|{#1}\rangle}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ket{x}\bra{x}
\]

\[
\ket{x}\!\bra{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might check whether a `\bra` immediately follows a `\ket`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{braket}

\renewcommand\bra[1]{{\langle{#1}|}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ket[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar\bra{\k@t{#1}\!}{\k@t{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\k@t[1]{{|{#1}\rangle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\ket{x}\bra{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288752/80949), if you want to use the no-space version of the command in moving arguments, like those in captions, you should make them robust. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{braket}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\ket[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar\bra{\k@t{#1}\!}{\k@t{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\k@t[1]{{|{#1}\rangle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{My cool caption $\ket{a}\bra{b}$.\label{fig:a}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]